# Does Clarity Design is compatible with Angular version 15?

Tags: angular, npm

I recently upgraded my project to Angular version 15. The version of clarity which I was using was-
**"@cds/core": "5.0.0",
"@clr/angular": "5.0.0",
"@clr/icons": "5.0.0",
"@clr/ui": "5.0.0",**
so i tried to change the clr version to there latest but i am getting the issue as below:-
[image]

i even tried with there few earlier versions but in all cases similar issue.

Any help here is Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is an open [github issue](https://github.com/vmware-clarity/ng-clarity/issues/392)

I.e. Angular 15 is not supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

I got mine to work by following the installation steps provided [here](https://core.clarity.design/get-started/developing/) and usage is provided through this [link](https://core.clarity.design/foundation/icons/)

Basic summary (after installation of course):
Add the following code to your component.ts

```
import '@cds/core/icon/register.js';
import { ClarityIcons, userIcon } from '@cds/core/icon';

ClarityIcons.addIcons(userIcon);
```

then use the cds icon as desired in your component.html file as follows

```
<cds-icon shape="user"></cds-icon>
```

I am sure for every icon you need to use you have to add it to your component.ts file first before using it in your component.html file.

Hope this helps!